# How to apply ColorFilter matrix to the direct file or image and save it in flutter?

Tags: flutter, colorfilter

This is such like a stupid question, but after struggled a few hours than come over here,
I have `ColorFilter` matrix array and file which is image.
So how to apply it, not for showing ,it is only for saving in local storage purpose.

```
File file=_sampleFile; // file contained image
ColorFilter cf= ColorFilter.matrix(filter[2]);
```

below code shows the color filtered image only in app

```
 ColorFiltered(
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.matrix(filter[2]),
            child: Image.File(_sampleFile),
          ),
```

but i want  it like

```
File colorFilterFile= _sampleFile.addColorFilter(ColorFilter.matrix(filter[2]));
```

or

```
Image image=Image.file(_sampleFile);
 Image colorFilterImage= image.addColorFilter(ColorFilter.matrix(filter[2]));
```

don't suggest screenshot from widget, it is not recommendation from my side
thank you

Comment: Hey, were you able to get a solution for this?